# clojurescript iterate over collection of map

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

I have a collection like this.

```
[{:id 101 :name "A"}, {:id 102 :name "B"}, {:id 103 :name "C"}]
```

I want to retrieve the complete map using id.
For ex, i want to find for id = 102.
so my function should return me this.

```
{:id 102 :name "B"}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: i'm new to clojurescript/functional prog so cant think of a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm able to find a way to do so.here is my answer

```
cljs.user=> (def ab [{:id 101 :name "A"}, {:id 102 :name "B"}, {:id 103 :name "C"}])
#'cljs.user/ab

cljs.user=> (some #(when (= (:id %) 102) %) ab)
{:name "B", :id 102}

cljs.user=>
```

Comment: Or `(first (filter (comp #{102} :id) ab))`

Answer (score 0):

```
(let [maps [{:id 1 :a "a"} {:id 2} {:id 3}]]
  (zipmap (map :id maps) maps))
```

Comment: it will work somehow but need to do some extra stuff for it. thanks !!